# How to exclude some word from regexp search?

Tags: regex, replace

I have XML-file with this structure

```
<item><rank>15</rank>...<price>100</price></item>
<item><rank>15</rank>...<price>200</price></item>
<item><rank>15</rank>...<price>500</price></item>
```

from the above **xml** the `...` means: some different tags which describe item somehow (may be any tag)

So I need to find item with `price=500` and replace `rank` for it.

```
<item><rank>\d+<\/rank>(.*)<price>500<\/price><\/item>
```

But this **RegExp** will find be content of these three tags starting from first `<item>` and `<price>500</price></item>` at the end.

So I need to exclude `</item>` from `(.*)` in the search.

Comment: use an xml parser.

Comment: Use capture groups? See [this](https://regex101.com/r/Ohr3Wa/1)

Comment: what programming languages do you use?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Ohr3Wa/2 this works if each item is separated by newline. Thank you!
@SumiStraessle

Comment: I thought that this task can be solved without programming scripts :(
@CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/Ohr3Wa/5)

```
/(?:<item>(?:<rank>(\d+)<\/rank>)(?:(?!<\/item>).)*(?:<price>500<\/price>)<\/item>)/igm
```

by using parentheses, you create capturing group ; the `?:` is a non-capturing group (meaning you're not interested in its content).
`igm` means case insensitive, global and multiline.
`(?!sth)` is a negative lookahead, meaning we will discard `sth`.

**Step by step: (from outer tags)**

```
(?:<item> ... <\/item>) # we're interested in things beginning with <item> and ending with </item> and we're not capturing the group

... (?:<rank>(\d+)<\/rank>) ... # there's a rank tag, we're not capturing it, but we're capturing the digits within the tag

... (?:(?!<\/item>).)* ... # the crux of the problem, we're looking at any character except <\/item>

... (?:<price>500<\/price>)<\/item>) # the "line" ends with these tags
```

Hope it helped.